# PDOException Error - Drupal 7

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7

When i created a image content type and add a content, get this error:

```
DOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'base.12' in 'where clause': SELECT base.tid AS tid, base.vid AS vid, base.name AS name, base.description AS description, base.format AS format, base.weight AS weight, v.machine_name AS vocabulary_machine_name FROM {taxonomy_term_data} base INNER JOIN {taxonomy_vocabulary} v ON base.vid = v.vid WHERE (base.12 = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 12 ) in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 196 of /Users/httdocs/includes/entity.inc).
```

But i don't use a taxonomy term, vocab, etc... How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PGSQL query like :-

```
 SELECT base.tid AS tid, base.vid AS vid, base.name AS name, base.description AS description, base.format AS format, base.weight AS weight, v.machine_name AS vocabulary_machine_name FROM taxonomy_term_data.base INNER JOIN taxonomy_vocabulary.v ON base.vid = v.vid WHERE (base.name = v.machine_name) ;
```

In your query you passed base.12, there no column with name 12. so it shows the error

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':db_condition_placeholder_0) LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1`

Comment: i don't know drupal... but that psql query has error at where condition... where condition like   WHERE(base.name= v.machine_name)